# What is the best practice to calculate the similarity between two couples of X And y

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have some values about one element. For example, `element1: values1, values2`.
For each element, I need to calculate the ‘score’ for a given number of  features.
Imagine that we have one feature that is represented as:

- An high score for the feature1 is given by an high score of value1 And a low score of value2.

So If I suppose that to an high score of value1 (1) And a low score of value2 (0) correspond an high score of ‘feature1’, what is the best practice to calculate the score of feature1 given as value1 And value2 two different scores? (For example value1=0.7, value=0.2).
I use Python as programming language, And I prefer to use sklearn ad module but every solution that fits well is accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First normalize your data. One type of normalization is to make your values1, values2 fit between the range [0,1].
2. Suppose the average 2-value characterization of the feature1 based on the normalized data is (.7, .2). For any new 2-values (x,y) compute the distance between (x,y) and (.7,.2)

When computing distance in machine learning, the sqrt component is usually not calculated.

```
dist^2 = (x-.7)^2 + (y-.2)^2
```

You might also be interested in calculating the error of a 2-value (x,y) w.r.t to (.7,.2) and can look into categorical cross entropy.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. One question: Is the re a way to calculate it throught a model such ad Logistic Regression? Because I always read in some documenta that this process is done throught a fittable model. Thank you

Comment: Least squared regression "finding a best fit line" is done by minimizing the distance between the line and the data points. Suppose your line - for simplicity - has equation f(a) = ma. Your goal is to find a value m that minimizes the sum of distances between f(a) and all data points - a distance between a line and a single point (x,y) is (a-x)^2+ (ma-y)^2.
One can use calculus to take the derivative of the sum of distance with respect to m to find a closed solution.

For more complex models with multiple params, you can still use the same equation but you'll need to estimate the minimum

Comment: by using techniques such as gradient descent which is how modern neural networks operate.